# make a sum of variable cells

Tags: excel, vba

i need your help with writhing a code. Below you can find an example of my sheet.
I need to add the values of the totals from the subs and the result needs to come in the cell next to subtotaal in the main block. But here is the catch, the number of subs are not always the same. That also means the cells are variable. and below this main is another main with his subcategories. 
the subs are added with another code. in this example there are only 2 subs, but in real the real sheet can be close to 20 subs.

I hope you guys understand what i'm trying to ask.
Grts

[image]

Comment: why not just use a formula?  K2 = "= sum("K4:K1000000") should do it (though of course you don't need to use 1000000 if 1000 will do).

Comment: I can't do that 'cause than the sum whill also add the values of the other mains. The total should be the sum of the subs of that main. (example main 1 total = sub1.1 + sub1.2 Main 2 total= sub 2.2+sub 2.3+sub2.4 etc.)

Comment: Ah, now I see.  there are no numbers in the main rows, so I didn't realize there would be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your first Main block is in row 3; if not, modify this as appropriate:
`=SUM(OFFSET($K4,0,0,MATCH("Main",$B4:$B1000,-1),1))`

This formula will sum all the values in a particular range; the `OFFSET` function builds the range. It starts from a defined reference cell - K4, in this case - then creates a range by moving down a specified number of rows, then right a specified number of columns - 0 rows, 0 columns for us - and returns a range of a specified height and 1 column in width.

We get the height from the `MATCH` function. This function looks for the first cell that starts with the word "Main" anywhere in the next 1,000 rows. The 1,000 here is more or less arbitrary, it can be any value that you're certain will find the next "Main" header.

The disadvantage of this formula is that if there isn't a match found - say if this is used on the last "Main" block and there's no Main header below it - it will return an error. We can control for that by adding an `IFERROR` function to get:
`=SUM(OFFSET($K4,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH("Main",$B$4:$B$1000,-1),50),1))`, which will assume a range of 50 cells if a match isn't found.